# "Enjoy!" vs. "Enjoy it!"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

When your friend/s telling you that he's doing something funny or traveling etc. What is the better way to react between the folowing two? Is it "enjoy!" or "enjoy it!"?

Answer (score 1):

There is no “correct way to react," although there are some things you could say that sound more natural than others.

You could use a one-word exclamation (“Enjoy!”), or, if you wanted to be more verbose, you might say one of these:

> Enjoy yourself!
>
> Have an enjoyable time.
>
> I hope you enjoy your trip!

Comment: 1^ Thank you. I saw someone who said "enjoy **it**!", then it's not common? (I edited my question to make it clearer)

Comment: There’s no real way to tell how common that phrasing would be. I don’t expect I’d find it very often, though.